# Why do we "roll" the car windows down, instead of "slide"

Tags: verbs

Rolling implies rotation and translation. Cranking implies the motion people used to do before power windows and Sliding is what actually happens to the window.

When and why did people start using the expression "roll the windows down," instead of something more descriptive?

Comment: In the UK, we wind them down.

Comment: Sort of like *dialing* a telephone number.  When is the last time you actually used a *dial* on a phone?

Comment: Or like computer programs that still use a floppy disk as the Save icon.

Comment: They see me rollin', they hatin'.

Comment: @GEdgar: I have a rotary dial application on my touchscreen mobile phone.

Comment: Nowadays I more frequently hear "put", as in "put the window down".

Comment: Related: _[What would be the word equivalent of paperwork in the digital age?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/33562/5822)_

Comment: In a "Baby Blues" cartoon the dad mentions a cordless phone. The kid says "Wait?! Phones used to have cords?!" Language lags behind the civilization the uses it. Delightfully so, in my opinion.

Comment: @Callithumpian, My back hurts. I spend the whole day _loading_ software.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: "Wow, you're a really stupid window." *(putting a window down)* (Being serious: This is why I've never heard a native English speaker say that. Actually, I've never heard *anyone* say it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In Australia we never say "roll", only ever "wind" or "put". "Put the window down" is a common phrase.

Comment: @Clonkex - Interesting! "Wind" is also used (rarely) in the U.S. in my experience, it seems to be older (like early 20th century), but I've never heard "put."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is in your question; *rolling* was the motion applied to windows before power windows. They did not physically apply force so as to directly slide them down, i.e. pushing them down with their hands, instead, they rolled (rotated) the lever, which in turn caused the windows to raise/lower. It is simply the description of the actual force being applied, not the effects of said force.

Comment: I would consider that cranking and not rolling. Rolling as in roller skates, or roller bearing.

Comment: @ja72 See the verb definition (b) of [roll](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll).

Comment: Rolling one's eyes is attested as long ago as 1510 according to Online Etymology Dictionary. The eyes typically do not have a translational motion as a result of this rolling ...

Answer (score 2):

It's a reasonable puzzle and baffled me as a child.

As you say rolling is rotation and translation. *Rolling up* however means winding something round a spool by rotating the spool (or winding the thing round the spool). Sometimes the spool will be translated, but usually it will be fixed. An efficent way of rolling something up is to crank a winch (using the law of the lever). Ropes on boats are rolled up this way. So it’s plausible that *rolling something up* became synonymous with turning a crank, even in cases where nothing was wound around a spool. And rolling something down became the opposite action.

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the definition of **roll**, you will see it involves a movement on an axis:

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roll?q=roll

As for **crank**, the same source states that the movement involved is made in order to start an engine. Therefore, it is more logical that ***roll a window up/down*** will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think originally car windows were “let down”, over time the common mechanism was to rotate a lever using a “window handle”, so the common usage became to “roll down” (the physical motion).

Whereas now, the common mechanism is to push an electronic toggle button.  Perhaps the new emerging common usage will again return to “let down”.

https://www.google.com/search?q=auto+window+handle&tbm=isch

Comment: "Perhaps the new emerging common usage will again return to “let down”." May be a while. We still say "dial a phone", while pushbutton phones have been around for 50+ years.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it came from the horse and buggy days when they had cloth covers for the windows and they literally had to roll the windows up?  Just a theory.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. I encourage you to add any references you can find as to this theory; however, personal conjecture without evidence is generally frowned upon. For further guidance, please see the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score -1):

I always assumed it was rolling up and down blinds on the original coaches that had no glass just material over the 'window' openings?